# HERE maps ZoomRectangle control usage

Tags: here-api

I looked for some examples of `H.ui.ZoomRectangle` usage but couldn't find one.

I tried to use it like this:

```js
const zoomrectangle =  H.ui.ZoomRectangle();
ui.addControl('zoomrectangle', zoomrectangle);
```

but got: `Uncaught TypeError: this.qa is not a function`

How should this control be used properly?

EDIT: Oh, my bad. I forgot to use `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is snipped code.

```
// Enable the default UI
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes);
ui.addControl('zoomRectangle', new H.ui.ZoomToRectangle());
```

Please refer the below example page.

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/zoom_rectangle

Happy Coding!